# Google AppScript: Execution Complete but it doesn't make any changes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

because of the work I do, I've gotten interested with coding, however im still in the process of learning, so I hope this won't spark angry comments, but I asked helped from chatGPT to help me with a script as I know a formula won't be of help (i think since its complex) with what I need so with that, I just want to copy columns D:K to the summary upon trigger every time a drop down of column K changes in any of the tab to the SUMMARY sheet.

the script runs when on CONSULTATION sheet, the whole row is moved or transferred to its specific tab. for example when I toggle Counseling, the whole data transfers to the counseling sheet. However, other than that trigger I also want specific columns copied to the SUMMARY sheet.

I'm not sure if this is okay, so I have attached the sharable link here so you visually see the specific columns I want copied as well: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Us8gURqn3I6Zk6TgiH4zpskIwnPZZJxNMtDWn8uYBoQ/edit?usp=sharing

I am expecting data in columns D:K to be copied to the SUMMARY sheet upon every dropdown trigger from both Consulation Sheet and Counseling Sheet as well as the whole row data to transfer to its speecific google tab every selected dropdown.

This is the scrip that I got so far base on what AI has helped me with:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e || !e.source) {
    return;
  }

  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = e.range.getColumn();

  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var dropdownColumn = 11; 

  // Check if the edited cell is in the column with the dropdown prompt
  if (editedColumn == dropdownColumn) {
    var selectedOption = e.value;
    
    
    if (selectedOption == "CONSULTATION") {
      var consultationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CONSULTATION");
      sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(consultationSheet.getRange(consultationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
      sheet.deleteRow(editedRow);
      return;
    }

    var destinationSheetName = "";

    
    switch (selectedOption) {
      case "NO RESPONSE":
        destinationSheetName = "No Response";
        break;
      case "TERMINATED AT CONSULTATION":
        destinationSheetName = "Terminated at Consultation";
        break;
      case "TERMINATED AT COUNSELING":
        destinationSheetName = "Terminated at Counseling";
        break;
      case "COUNSELING":
        destinationSheetName = "Counseling";
        break;
      case "EXTERNAL REFERRAL":
        destinationSheetName = "External Referral";
        break;
      default:
        
        return;
    }

    
    var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
    sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));

    
    sheet.deleteRow(editedRow);
  } 
  var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editedColumn = editedRange.getColumn();
  
  var targetSheetName = "SUMMARY";
  var targetColumns = "D:K";
  
  if (editedColumn == editedSheet.getRange("K:K").getColumn()) {
    var targetSheet = editedSheet.getParent().getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    
    
    editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedSheet.getRange(targetColumns).getColumn(), 1, targetColumns.split(":").length).copyTo(targetRange);
    
    
    editedSheet.deleteRow(editedRow);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.e.range.getSheet();
  const ddc = 11;
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == ddc && e.value) {
    let selopt = e.value;
    if (selopt == "CONSULTATION") {
      let consultationSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("CONSULTATION");
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(consultationSheet.getRange(consultationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    }
    const oA = ["NO RESPONSE", "TERMINATED AT CONSULTATION", "TERMINATED AT COUNSELING", "COUNSELING", "EXTERNAL REFERRAL"]
    const shts = ["No Response", "Terminated at Consultation", "Terminated at Counseling", "Counseling", "External Referral"]
    let idx = oA.indexOf(selopt);
    if (~idx) {
      let destinationSheetName = shts[idx];
    }
    let destinationSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    let targetSheet = sh.getParent().getSheetByName("SUMMARY");
    let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart, 1).copyTo(targetRange);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

This may not work without  some tweaking because following line makes absolutely no sense to me:

```
editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedSheet.getRange(targetColumns).getColumn(), 1, targetColumns.split(":").length).copyTo(targetRange);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Cooper.
I understand what you mean by the line that didn't make sense, I looked up and searched how some lines can affect the script or maybe I lacked more research and understanding.